# Parse string to arguments

Tags: matlab

I have a character vector like so:

```
string = 'a(0:2), b(3), c(rand(4, 5)*0.1)';
```

I'd like to use this char array as input arguments to a function. The arguments would then be:

```
a(0:2)
b(3)
c(rand(4, 5)*0.1)
```

How can I parse the string into those input arguments?
At first glance, one could split the string with the `', '` separator, but it would fail for the third argument obviously.

Comment: You're basically asking for a parser, which is too broad of a question here. Also, even if you did parse the string, you're going to be faced with evaluating it using `eval`. Always remember: `eval` is evil - you've reached this point in your code where you need to use it, turn around and re-write your code so that you don't have to! It's usually quicker and more maintainable to use better methods.

Comment: You're right, it's probably too broad in scope, since it the solution resembles a parser.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is using `split` as following:

```
expressions = split(string, "), ");
```

Then add `")"` at the end of each string in `expressions`.

Comment: ... and strip the commas/whitespace from start of each string